# How to get a rid from "Warning: Camera failed" error?

Tags: custom-roms, camera, rom, android-versions, stock-rom

I have a Samsung Galaxy J7. It's camera was destroyed by an accident. So everytime I open camera, snapchat etc apps it shows "Warning: Camera failed". For a reason I need my phone to take at least a black screen on snapchat by clicking on the button. Is it possible to edit the rom to make the camera take at least a black screen instead of showing "Camera failed" and how?

Answer (score -1):

How to fix “Unfortunately, Camera has stopped” error on Galaxy J7
Step 1: Reboot your device 
Step 2: Restart your J7 in safe mode
Step 3: Clear the cache and data of the Camera app and other related apps
Step 4: Factory reset your Galaxy J7